# Block target="_blank" popup with Javascript

Tags: javascript, popup, target

I would like to know if it is possible to block the opening of a new window from a certain element in Javascript

I tried that but it doesn't work:

```js
var links= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
    links[i].setAttribute('target', '_top');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp), the default target is "_self". Try the following:

```
var links= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (curLink of links){
    curLink.setAttribute('target', '_self');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, you can't do something like: 

If a new tab opens and the link is https://url.com/ then we close the tab?

Comment: If you run the code from the answer via `onload` it will change every link on the page to have `target="_self"`.
If you're trying to block one particular link from opening in a new window you need to target that specific link using `getElementById` (assuming the link has the id attribute set), or you can do something like `if(curLink.href="http://www.asdf.com"){ curLink.setAttribute('target', '_self'); }`, but you would need to match the url exactly.